# Bootstrap.inc error appearing on website

Tags: views

When I go to my database website at kctd.org/community, I get this error:

> Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/home/kctd/public_html/community/sites/all/modules/views/modules/translation/views_handler_filter_node_language.inc' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/kctd/public_html/community/includes/bootstrap.inc on line 3069

I have no idea what that means. The last action I did was extending the result of my view filter to include user's email. When I clicked save, this popped up. I cannot log in to even switch to maintenance mode.

What can I do?

Comment: It seems like the file `views_handler_filter_node_language.inc` has moved from `modules/views/modules/translation` to `modules/views/modules/locale`. If you flush your cache this should solve your problem. Check out this link: http://drupal.org/node/1744950

Comment: You should write this up as an answer and include info on how to flush cache on a crashed site thermally bootstrap.

Comment: clear cache and run cron.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that `views_handler_filter_node_language.inc` was moved from `views/modules/translation` to `views/modules/locale`. I guess you have updated the views module but not rebuilt you registry. 
You should be able to solve this by flushing the cache. [Here's](http://drupal.org/node/1744950) a issue, addressing the same problem.

Notice that whenever you update a module you should also call the update script located at `example.com/update.php`.

To flush the cache using [drush](http://drupal.org/project/drush) use the following syntax: `drush cc all`.

You could also try to clear the `cache_bootstrap` table using:

```
mysql -uusername -ppassword -hhostname database -e"DELETE FROM cache_bootstrap WHERE cid='system_list';"`
```

or

```
drush sql-query "DELETE FROM cache_bootstrap WHERE cid='system_list';"
```

**Backup your database before trying the above**

If you still have trouble, you could also try to disable the views module using something like this:

```
mysql -uusername -ppassword -hhostname database -e"UPDATE system SET status='0' WHERE name='views';"
```

or

```
drush dis views
```

You might need to clear the cache as in the previous step for this to take effect.

Here you can find more information about disabling a module manually: [Disabling modules manually in the database](http://drupal.org/node/157632)

Answer (score 1):

For me it was simply a case of having moved module folders in sites/all/modules to sites/all/modules/CONTRIBUTED - I was trying to clean up my folder structure a bit.

The issue resolved as soon as I moved the module folders back to their original placement.

Answer (score 0):

I would do two things.

Restart Apache and make sure your APC has enough memory.  Errors about require and/or include can be indicative of APC not having enough memory.

If that doesnt fix things, download the registry rebuild module for drush, and run it. Take a database backup first as a precaution.

Answer (score 0):

1. How I got Here; 
   I tried to update some modules using the 'available updates' option in the modules configuration menu
2. The solution in my own case; First I had to download the following files; views, views_block_area, views_slideshow again which can be found here http://drupalmodules.com/ or https://drupal.org/
3. Next, I unzipped both files and connected to my host-machine using ftp, then I navigated to ../sites/all/modules and overwrite the directories
4. further I also made backups of the aforementioned directories in case I may have to roll back configuration